# running Map on a nested RDD

Tags: python, pyspark, mapreduce

I have a huge RDD with hundreds of millions of records that its structure is like this:
`rdd.collect()` results in:

```py
[['t1', 't5', 't7'],
['t1', 't7'], ['t2', 't3'],
['t1', 't3', 't4'], ...]
```

And suppose this is all of the RDD and not a snapshot of it. What I want to have is this:
`desired.collect()` results in:

```py
('t1', <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7f534107ead0>)
('t5', <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7f534107e090>)
('t7', <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7f534107e050>)
('t2', <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7f534107efd0>)
('t3', <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7f534107e510>)
('t4', <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7f534107ed50>)
```

Where for example:

```py
for x in desired.collect()[0][1]:
  print(x)
```

results in:

```
t5
t7
t3
t4
```

because they share a list with `t1`.

Comment: Vey confusing. what do u want to do. your sentence is not clear

Comment: I have an RDD containing a list of lists. And I want to have another RDD, made of pairs whose key is elements inside the original RDD's nested lists, and the values are the elements that share a list with the key in original RDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from your last question we can use same method along with groupbykey and mapvalues

```
import itertools
data2=[['t1', 't5', 't7'],['t1', 't7'], ['t2', 't3'],['t1', 't3', 't4']]
rd2=sc.parallelize(data2)
rd2=rd2.flatMap(lambda x:itertools.combinations(x,2)).groupByKey().mapValues(set)

for x in rd2.collect()[0][1]:
  print(x)

#output
t5
t7
t3
t4
```

Edit - Have added .mapValues(set) to remove duplicates from results